# Bootstrap modal's top gets cut off when the modal content increases?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a bootstrap modal which is vertically centered. But when the modal content increases in size, the top gets cut off. How can I avoid this?

Code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h3>Vertical Center Modal</h3>
            <a href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal">Click to trigger modal</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Vertically Centered Modal</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
                <p>Added lorem ipsum here in the fiddle</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#myModal .modal-dialog {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0,-50%);
    -o-transform: translate(0,-50%);
    transform: translate(0,-50%);
    top: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Here is the link to the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x73u6tgb/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding a `max-height` property to the modal-body would work. Something like follows:

```
.modal-body {
  max-height: 400px;
  overflow-y: auto; // for scroll bars
}
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

If we you want to get it done based on percentage. For example, if you want to give a height and width of 90% for your modal, you achieve it as shown below in case of Angular 10 + Bootstrap 4 combination.

Component from where the modal will be invoked:

- Ensure that you use a new css class name in the modal service open parameter of "windowClass". I have used the name "my-modal"
- give the size as "lg"

```
@Component({
  selector: 'base-component',
  templateUrl: './base.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./base.component.scss']
})
export class BaseComponent {

  constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) { }

  openModal() {
    const modalRef = this.modalService.open(MyComponent,
      {
        windowClass: "my-modal",
        keyboard: false,
        size: "lg",
        centered: true,
      });

  }
}
```

Then define the css rules as shown below in styles.scss:

```
// To set the width to 90%
.my-modal .modal-lg {
    max-width: 90%;
}

// Since you specified the size as "lg", the generated bootstrap template 
// would have the class "modal-lg" applied to it. If you give the size as "sm", 
// you might have to change the css rule below and replace "modal-lg" with "modal-sm"
.my-modal .modal-lg .modal-content{
     height: 100%;
}

.modal.my-modal.show .modal-dialog {
     height: 90%;
}
```